# Ubuntu 18 upgrade failing to login after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

Went from clean recently installed ubuntu 17 to 18 and after upgrade I rebooted and entered login info and it just freezes on the purple screen of death.  Machine is a dell xps 15 ,. I tried installing the Nvidia 390 drivers to no avail

Comment: Time to restore from your backup and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the release version of 18.04.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1766137

The problem is that the login succeeds, but GNOME fails to launch. Here are your options:

1. The problem most often occurs when you type your password wrong, and then type it correctly on a subsequent attempt. If, when you mistype your password, you then click "cancel" to go back to the initial screen and choose your username again, type your password correctly, you should be able  to get to the desktop.
2. Some have reported that installing the latest Nvidia drivers helps. This hasn't worked for me, but you can try it.
3. Switch to a different display manager until it is fixed. This can be somewhat technical so I consider it out of scope for this answer.
4. Switch to a different desktop environment. The problem only occurs in Gnome, so you can click the gear icon in the login screen and pick "unity" instead of "gnome" and it should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I did these and it fixed the issue.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Login

```
$ sudo apt-get install xorg
$ mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Chose gdm3

```
reboot
```